# smack message body The symbol is the escape

Tags: java, smack

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("msg",101);
chat.sendMessage(JSONObkect.fromObject(map).toString,"xxx@xx.com");
{"msg":101}
```

in DEBUG json become

> {& quot;msg& quot;:101}

the " become & quot;

how can i do?

the server can't change.

Comment: chat.sendMessage("{\"msg\":101}","xxxx@xx.com"); also become

Comment: the server get it was "{& quot;msg& quot;:101}"

Comment: I don't get the point. Smack uses his data model (stanza - packet - message - iq) as Java class to expose XML format. If you have something  nativly in JSON, transform it in XML, not in JsonObject...